# Axios spread() with unknown number of callback parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I need to process an unknown number of AJAX requests (1 or more) with axios, and I am not sure how to handle the response. I want something along the lines of:

```
let urlArray = [] // unknown # of urls (1 or more)

axios.all(urlArray)
.then(axios.spread(function () {
  let temp = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments[i].length; i++)
    temp.push(arguments[i].data);
}));
```

where arguments will contain the callback responses sent by axios. The problem is that `arguments` contains the given string urls instead of the actual responses. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You somewhere will need to make the actual requests. And then don't use `spread` but only `then` to receive the array of results:

```
let urlArray = [] // unknown # of urls (1 or more)

let promiseArray = urlArray.map(url => axios.get(url)); // or whatever
axios.all(promiseArray)
.then(function(results) {
  let temp = results.map(r => r.data);
  …
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the spread ... My results are just Array(3) [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts If you are getting an array, and want to work with an array instead of three specific values, then you should not use `spread` (and even if you do, just use modern destructuring syntax instead of `spread`). If your problem is that you get `undefined` instead of some expected value, that has nothing to do with `spread` but with the function that is creating your promises.