# Array in object empty when passed or JSON.stringified

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension where I'm sending an object (connectionStatus) from a background script to a content script. The object contains an array (supportedServiceContracts), which is empty when I log the object in content.js even though I can see it has data when I log it in background.js just before I send it.

Why is that?

**UPDATE:**

I should also mention that the array part of the object gets empty if I apply `JSON.stringify()` on the object. See screenshot.

[image]

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "axios.min.js" });
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "content.js" });

var connectionStatus = {};

chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
    },
    function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        var url = tab.url;
        var urlString = new URL(url);
        var childHSAId = urlString.searchParams.get("childhsaid");

        if (childHSAId) {
            var healthcareFacilityHSAId = urlString.searchParams.get("hsaid");
            connectionStatus.healthcareFacilityHSAId = healthcareFacilityHSAId;
            connectionStatus.childHSAId = childHSAId;
            getConnectionStatusData(childHSAId);                
        } else {
            var healthcareFacilityHSAId = urlString.searchParams.get("hsaId");
            connectionStatus.healthcareFacilityHSAId = healthcareFacilityHSAId;
            getConnectionStatusData(healthcareFacilityHSAId);
        }

});

async function getConnectionStatusData(logicalAddress) {

    let serviceDomains = await axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/serviceDomains.json', {
                                params: {
                                    namespace: "crm:scheduling"
                                }
                            });

    serviceDomainId = serviceDomains.data[0].id;

    let connectionPoints = await axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/connectionPoints.json', {
                                params: {
                                    platform: "NTJP",
                                    environment: "PROD"
                                }
                            });

    connectionPointId = connectionPoints.data[0].id;

    var d = new Date(connectionPoints.data[0].snapshotTime);
    var options = { hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit' };

    snapshotTime = d.toLocaleDateString('se-SE', options)

    connectionStatus.snapshotTime = snapshotTime;

    let logicalAddresss = await axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/logicalAddresss.json', {
                                params: {
                                    logicalAdress: logicalAddress,
                                    serviceConsumerHSAId: "SE2321000016-92V4",
                                    connectionPointId: connectionPointId
                                }
                            });

    if (logicalAddresss.data === undefined || logicalAddresss.data.length == 0) {

        connectionStatus.errorMessage = "HSA-id " + logicalAddress + " är inte registrerat i Ineras API för Etablerad samverkan i vården. API:t uppdaterades med data från Nationella tjänsteplattformens tjänstekatalog vid " + snapshotTime + ".";

        sendMessage();

        return;

    } else {

        logicalAddressId = logicalAddresss.data[0].id;

    }

    let serviceConsumers = await axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/serviceConsumers.json', {
                                params: {
                                    connectionPointId: connectionPointId,
                                    logicalAddressId: logicalAddressId
                                }
                            });

    consumer = serviceConsumers.data.filter(obj => {
          return obj.hsaId === "SE2321000016-92V4"
        });

    serviceConsumerId = consumer[0].id;

    let cooperations = await axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/cooperations.json', {
                                params: {
                                    connectionPointId: connectionPointId,
                                    logicalAddressId: logicalAddressId,
                                    serviceDomainId: serviceDomainId,
                                    serviceConsumerId: serviceConsumerId,
                                    include: "serviceContract"
                                }
                            });

    var supportedServiceContracts = [];

    cooperations.data.forEach(function(cooperation) {

        axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/serviceProducers.json', {
                    params: {
                        connectionPointId: connectionPointId,
                        logicalAddressId: logicalAddressId,
                        serviceDomainId: serviceDomainId,
                        serviceConsumerId: serviceConsumerId,
                        serviceContractId: cooperation.serviceContract.id
                    }
        }).then(response => {

            supportedServiceContracts.push({serviceContract: cooperation.serviceContract.namespace, serviceProducerDescription: response.data[0].description, serviceProducerHSAId: response.data[0].hsaId});

        });


    });

    connectionStatus.supportedServiceContracts = supportedServiceContracts;

    sendMessage();

    function sendMessage() {

        console.log(connectionStatus); // The array supportedServiceContracts has data
        console.log(JSON.stringify(connectionStatus)); // The array supportedServiceContracts has NO data

        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, connectionStatus);
        });

    };

}
```

});

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request); // The array supportedServiceContracts has NO data
```

});

Comment: I should also mention that the array part of the object gets empty if I apply `JSON.stringify()` on the object.

Comment: You're populating the supportedServiceContracts array AFTER you send the message. You're seeing the array contents in the first console.log only because devtools shows a *reference* to the original object and shows its contents dynamically. The solution is to use Promise.all on cooperations.data, and send the message in its then().

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify(connectionStatus.supportedServiceContracts)`  to see if the array itself cannot be parsed alone?

Comment: @wOxxOm: Oh, I didn't know devtools did that. Thanks! Do you mind explaining what I should do in more detail?

Comment: @Cold Cerberus: Yes, I did. It can't be parsed. I think wOxxOm found the problem. I just don't understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Send the message after completing **all** network requests by using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) - the browser will automatically enqueue all the requests and emit just a bunch at once, also there are JS libraries that allow customizing the amount of parallel jobs in Promise.all.
- Use the `tab` parameter of browserAction.onClicked instead of requerying the active tab, which is both redundant and wrong - the user may switch tabs while your code is working
- Use the [WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) to call the API with Promise/async in a straightforward fashion

---

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(async tab => {

  // enqueue without waiting so we don't block the subsequent async code 
  const contentScriptReady = Promise.all([
    browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "axios.min.js"}),
    browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"}),
  ]);

  const connectionStatus = {};

  /* snipped */

  connectionStatus.supportedServiceContracts = await Promise.all(
    cooperations.data.map(cooperation =>
      axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/serviceProducers.json', {
        params: {
          connectionPointId,
          logicalAddressId,
          serviceDomainId,
          serviceConsumerId,
          serviceContractId: cooperation.serviceContract.id,
        },
      }).then(response => ({
        serviceContract: cooperation.serviceContract.namespace,
        serviceProducerDescription: response.data[0].description,
        serviceProducerHSAId: response.data[0].hsaId,
      }))
    )
  );

  await contentScriptReady;
  browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, connectionStatus);

});
```

P.S. Try reworking your code so that several axios.get requests are invoked in parallel by using Promise.all instead of waiting for each one to complete sequentially.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time! When I run that code I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined` on line 1.

Comment: As you can see in the third bullet point the code uses WebExtension polyfill. Don't just run the code from the internet, analyze it first e.g. read the description/whatever.

Comment: Sorry, this stuff is really advanced for me. I managed to implement the WebExtension polyfill so "browser is not defined" is gone. But I can't seem to merge your code with mine properly. I can't just copy/paste the missing chunk where `/* snipped */`is because things are encapsulated. I would REALLY appreciate it if you pasted the full code.

Comment: I don't have the full code, I would have to rework it for you, which is outside of the scope. Other answers are probably easier to incorporate if you don't want to rework your code as suggested here.

Comment: So the other parts of background.js at the top is wrong? I can't copy/paste that stuff to your code and have it work?

Comment: I don't know as I didn't even look there, I suspect some really trivial changes are needed.

Comment: Dude, I totally got it to work! Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it. Now I have to read up on promises so I understand what my code does :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the array inside the .then function:

```
cooperations.data.forEach(function(cooperation) {

    axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/serviceProducers.json', {
                params: {
                    connectionPointId: connectionPointId,
                    logicalAddressId: logicalAddressId,
                    serviceDomainId: serviceDomainId,
                    serviceConsumerId: serviceConsumerId,
                    serviceContractId: cooperation.serviceContract.id
                }
    }).then(response => {
        supportedServiceContracts.push({serviceContract: cooperation.serviceContract.namespace, serviceProducerDescription: response.data[0].description, serviceProducerHSAId: response.data[0].hsaId});
        connectionStatus.supportedServiceContracts = supportedServiceContracts;
        sendMessage();
    });


});

function sendMessage() {

    console.log(connectionStatus); // The array supportedServiceContracts has data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(connectionStatus)); // The array supportedServiceContracts has NO data

    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, connectionStatus);
    });
};
```

Or use the async-await pattern you use elsewhere...

Comment: I noticed that in my original code and corrected it there. I have corrected it here in the question now. The type is not the problem though. Thanks!

Comment: Questions: on those two lines are you saying JSON.stringify(connectionStatus) shows an empty object but console.log(connectionStatus) doesn't? Also, why do you wrap connectionStatus in braces when calling chrome.tabs.sendMessage?

Comment: The object is not entirely empty, just the array in it.

You, Sir, have a very good eye! The curly braces are not in my original code. I have removed them here too. That's not the problem either though.

Comment: I attached a screenshot of the control panel.

Comment: I notice the line supportedServiceContracts.push({serviceContract: ... is inside a promise .then function(async), but you proceed directly to sending the message. Unless I am missing something, you should have the sendMessage inside the .then function.

Comment: The line you referring to is within a `forEach`. If I would to put the sendMessage function in there, I would send multiple messages. I want to only send one. This is not the problem though, as one of the `console.log` which are executed just before the sendMessage function, shows data in the array. Thanks!

Comment: You're right re the loop. Nonetheless I'm not sure how this can work without the await keyword. Are you sure that's not missing from the posted code?

Comment: No, that's the entire code. The message (the object connectionStatus) contains all the data I need and it gets sent. That part works fine. The problem is that the array (supportedServiceContracts) within the message shows up blank when applying `JSON.stringify()` to the message or when looking at the message in the tab it is being sent to. I think those symptoms are related.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188719/discussion-between-see-sharper-and-rawland-hustle).

Answer (score 0):

The array you have declared `supportedServiceContracts` is still empty when the method `sendMessage()` was called. This is because the line with the `supportedServiceContracts.push(...)` is inside a `Promise` callback function. By the time `sendMessage()` is called, not even at least one of the API request promise is resolved which means nothing has been pushed to the `supportedServiceContracts` yet.

You will have to:

1. Wait for all the individual request that pushes values to `supportedServiceContracts`
2. Then you are safe to call `sendMessage()` AFTER the requests are resolved.

One way to do this is to make use of [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which will make you a Promise that will resolve after all the promises passed as an array have resolved. You can call `sendMessage()` in the callback function of your `Promise.all()`

Example:

```
const supportedServiceContracts = [];
const apiRequestPromises= [];

cooperations.data.forEach(cooperation => {
  apiRequestPromises.push(
    axios.get('http://api.ntjp.se/coop/api/v1/serviceProducers.json', {
        params: {
            connectionPointId: connectionPointId,
            logicalAddressId: logicalAddressId,
            serviceDomainId: serviceDomainId,
            serviceConsumerId: serviceConsumerId,
            serviceContractId: cooperation.serviceContract.id
        }
    })
  );
});

Promise.all(apiRequestPromises)
  .then(responses => {
    // Populate your array first
    responses.forEach(response => {
        supportedServiceContracts.push({
            serviceContract: cooperation.serviceContract.namespace,
            serviceProducerDescription: response.data[0].description,
            serviceProducerHSAId: response.data[0].hsaId
        });
    });
    // Then do whatever you want with it
    sendMessage();
  });
```

Please try to make something similar with this as this is just a pseudo code and might not work directly if you copy paste only. This is only theoretical and written directly here without any tests.