# Is there a way to get and ref two or more local json file using vue and axios

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

I am using vue to prototype some html components. Is there a way to get vue to recognize two json files?

vue.js

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#douglas-laing',
   data: {
    products: [],
    contentPanels: []
},

created() {
axios
  .get( `products.json`, `contentPanel.json`)
  .then(response => {
    // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
    this.products = response.data;
    this.contentPanels = response.data;
  })
},

computed: {


}, // end computed

  methods: { }

});
```

in the html

```
<template v-for="contentPanel in contentPanels">
    {{ contentPanel.description }}
</template>
```

in the json file

```
  [
      {
        "description": "this is a content panel test",
      }
  ]
```

Comment: I think axios is an http-based promise.. so it expects a valid route url parameter in order to fetch data with the get method. Idk if you can just feed it a local json file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promise All with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669596/promise-all-with-axios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with axios.all(), something like:

```js
methods: {
    getProducts() {
        return axios.get('/products.json');
    },
    getContentPanel() {
        return axios.get('/contentPanel.json');
    }
},
created(){
    axios.all([this.getProducts(), this.getContentPanel()])
    .then(axios.spread(function (products, contentPanel) {
        // Do something with the values
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

got it

created() {
    axios
      .get( `products.json`)
      .then(response => {
        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
        this.products = response.data;
      })
    axios
      .get( `contentPanel.json`)
      .then(response => {
        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
        this.contentPanels = response.data;
      })
  },