# How to get request multipe axios at the same time in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, axios

[image: example]

reponse of my request is so slowly it will not perform request at same time..

```
axios
    .all([        
        axios.get('/api/completed'),
        axios.get('/api/newproject'),
        axios.get('/api/onprogress'),
        axios.get('/api/onsale'),
        axios.get('/api/project_summary'),
    ]) 
    .then(axios.spread((onprogress, onsale,completed,project_summary,newproject) => {   
     // output of req.
    
    }));
```

Comment: `axios` is doing everything right. What backend did you use?

Comment: this may be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669596/promise-all-with-axios

Comment: @JulianS I'm using laravel framework

Comment: @NotaPro and currently you test it on localhost with the server running wiht `php artisan serve`? If so, then it is a Problem with the `php artisan serve` server, because it is single threaded and can only handle one request at a time

Comment: @JulianS Yes I'm running it on localhost I'm using xampp.. pls help me what can I do ..

Comment: anyone can help me to configure xampp? :(

Answer (score 0):

This depends probably on your backend. As seen in your screenshot, the browser starts all requests at once. It seems that your backend can only handle one request at a time and therefor sends the responses one after the other.

If you have a Node.js backend (just a guess, Node.js is single-threaded by default) you can check if you use some sync I/O operations and replace them with async operations. This can help that your backend processes run more "in parallel" and reduce the overall time.

Comment: I'm using laravel and vue.js  how can I make this on the backend?

Comment: I think Laravel has a throttle mechanism where you can protect your api to be misused and limit the parallel usage, Maybe the is something configured that prevents your api calls from being processed parallel. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#rate-limiting