# How to use Promise.all with Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

```
    Promise.all(purchaseOrderUpdate.map((purchaseOrder) => {
      return axiosInstance.put(CreatePOUrl + "/" + purchaseOrder.id.toString() + '?correlationId=1', purchaseOrder)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("say 1st")
      })
    }))
    console.log("say last")
```

I thought by returning the axiosInstance, it is returning a list of promises which should all be resolved before "say last" is printed.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promise All with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669596/promise-all-with-axios)

Answer (score 4):

`Promise.all` is itself a promise, so you would still need to either `await` it, or `console.log` in it's `.then`:

```
Promise.all(purchaseOrderUpdate.map((purchaseOrder) => {
  return axiosInstance.put(CreatePOUrl + "/" + purchaseOrder.id.toString() + '?correlationId=1', purchaseOrder)
  .then(response => {
    console.log("say 1st")
  })
})).then(() => {
    console.log("say last")
});
```