# store multiple api calls in one react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, ecmascript-6, axios

I have multiple api's that are returning same type of data but from different areas but the data type is the same only the values are different, and I want to store them all in one react state.

So I have this state:

```
  let [infoData1, setInfoData1] = useState({ infoData1: [] });
  let [infoData2, setInfoData2] = useState({ infoData2: [] });
```

and the axios calls :

```
function multipleApiCall() {
    const headers = {
      "X-Api-Key": "the-api-key-00",
    };
    axios.get(
        "http:url-to-data/ID1",
        { headers }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setInfoData1(response.data);
        return axios.get(
          "http:url-to-data/ID2",
          { headers }
        )
      })
   .then(response => {
      setInfoData2(response.data);
  })
}
```

and afterward I want to use a `.map()` to list the result but because I have 2 states I cannot concatenate them. So how can I have all data from those two api's in just one state or maybe another approach ?

Comment: `Axios.get()` returns a Promise. so you could await all promises and derive the data from there. more info in this accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669775/13150902

Please note that with this method, if 1 request fails the `Promise.all()` fails for both requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [infoData, setInfoData] = useState([]);

const headers = {
    "X-Api-Key": "the-api-key-00",
};

const urls = ["http:url-to-data/ID1", "http:url-to-data/ID2"];

function multipleApiCall() {

    const promises = urls.map(url => axios.get(url, { headers }));

    Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
        let data = [];

        responses.forEach(response => {
            data = data.concat(response.data);
        });

        setInfoData(data);
    });
}
```