# Vue - Wait for for loop to fetch all items asynchronously

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, fetch

i have an array of data to be fetched, so i have to use a for loop to fetch all the data, but i want to do it asynchronously (multiple calls at the same time).
After having fetched the data i also want to do some data manipulation, so i need to run code AFTER all the data has been fetched

```
for (var e in this.dataTofetch) {
  axios
    .get("https://www.example.com/api/" + e)
    .then((response) => this.fetchedData.push(response.data));
}
this.manipulateData();
```

The problem is that whenever i reach the manipulateData function, fetchedData is empty.

Also i tried doing it synchronously using await and it works but it becomes very slow when making multiple calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
Promise.all(
  this.dataTofetch.map(e => axios.get(`https://www.example.com/api/${e}`)),
).then(responses =>
  responses.forEach(r => this.fetchedData.push(r.data)),
);

this.manipulateData();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)-method.

```
const promises = this.dataTofetch.map(e =>axios
    .get("https://www.example.com/api/" + e))
Promise.all(promises).then(arrOfRes => {
    // Do something with the responses (arrOfRes[x] = response)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I can think of is to use [`Promise.all()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-promise-all-method/). You will leave out the `.then`-handler, because `axios.get()` returns you a promise.

An exact implementation example can be found here at StackOverflow: [Promise All with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669596/promise-all-with-axios).