Wait for multiple times axios access finished
I have script like this below.
It start multiple API access.
    var temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < `10;i++){
        var url = `http://www.myapi.com/api/?id=${i}`;
        axios.get(url).then(res =>{
            temp[i] = res['data'];
            //I want to do something if every API get the results.
            }).catch(res => {
            console.log("axios error");
        });
    }
    

Now I want to wait every 10 api access finished.
Is it possible or how can I do this?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

You could use Promise.all to wait for multiple requests,


Promise.all([
    fetch('https://example.ex/articles'),
    fetch('https://example.ex/authors')
]).then((responses) => {
    // JSON object from each of the responses
    return Promise.all(responses.map((response) => {
        return response.json();
    }));
}).then((data) => {
    // You would do something with both sets of data 
    console.log(data);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});




This is the same as the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669596/promise-all-with-axios
